# What action can be taken on a B2B portal which collects upfront import fees

Tags: international

What action can be taken on a B2B portal which collects upfront import fees through their courier service providers to a country which does not impose any import fees for importers. The worst thing is that they are collecting from buyers behalf and paying to the customs department at origin which is not true!

Answer (score 1):

### Duties and Fees are not the same thing

Duties are levied by states on imports. Fees are charged for providing a service. I can charge you a fee for importing a product irrespective of if I have to pay duty or not.